# How do I use this object pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have a device which has 2 sensors for a breaking section and a stop section.
The sensors are debounced using my debounceClass.

Currently I have:

```
Debounce breakSection(  breakSectionPin ) ;
Debounce stopSection(   stopSectionPin ) ;

void debounce() // runs every 50ms
{   
    breakSection.debounce() ;
    stopSection.debounce() ;
}

// somewhere in code
    if( breakSection.getState() == FALLING ) doSomethingOnce() ;
```

In the next generation device, the breaking sensor and stop sensor become ambiguous. The sensor which is made first becomes the breaking sensor and the other one becomes the stop sensor.

I would like this to solve with a pointer, but I am not sure if it will work.

```
Debounce section1(  breakSectionPin ) ;
Debounce section2(   stopSectionPin ) ;

Debounce* breakSection ( 0 ) ;  // how does this work with arguments?
Debounce* stopSection  ( null ) ;

void debounce() // runs every 50ms
{   
    section1.debounce() ;
    section2.debounce() ;
}

void readSensors()
{
    if( section1.getState() == FALLING )
    {
        breakSection = &section1 ;
        stopSection  = &section2 ;
    }
    if( section2.getState() == FALLING )
    {
        breakSection = &section2 ;
        stopSection  = &section1 ;
    }   
}

// somewhere in code
    if( breakSection -> getState() == FALLING ) doSomethingOnce() ;
```

Will this work / am I doing it right?
And if not how can I solve it?
Should I use 'new' for this? like:

```
Debounce *breakSection = new Debounce ; // ??
```

Comment: Your pointers need to refer to valid objects in order to call member functions. Neither `0` nor `null` seem to be valid objects. Using `new Debounce` is one option to create such an object (with dynamic memory allocation)

Comment: the 0 / null I entered, was to 'fill in' something for the argument for the constructor. The constructor of the class takes one byte as argument

Comment: So you want something like `Debounce *breakSection = new Debounce(0);`? Did you try using that?

Comment: I do not know if the pointer object needs the argument to be filled in with someting. I figured that the value itself does not matter because later on I will be doing: ```breakSection = &section2 ;```. So I do not know if I should be typing: ```Debounce *breakSection = new Debounce ;```  or ```Debounce *breakSection = new Debounce(0);```
Would it be a good idea to remove the argument in the constructor and add the IO pin via a method somewhere during setup?

Comment: Also I am currently not behind my home PC and I cannot compile or test my project at this time.